# How does curl works for VDI and a computer?

Tags: curl, artifactory, vdi

I have a question regarding CURL command for VDI and regular computer. I have an artifactory Jfrog repository hosted on a VDI. I tried using curl to get the data and it works. However when I tried to get the data using curl on my own computer, it refused to connect (curl:(28) Failed to connect to artifactory-scanner.company.com port 443 after 21083 ms:Timed out.).

Why is it this way, is there a solution to fix ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the connection refused error you are facing while connecting to the Artifactory instance from your computer, this error will also occur when there is a connectivity issue or firewall between the client and hence the server is blocking access (also check local firewalls).

Also please do use telnet to connect to the IP/port to test connectivity. This removes any potential issues from your application.